# How to refresh a webpage in php when file contents has changed?

Tags: php, web, refresh, file-read

I Was wondering if it was possible to refresh a php webpage when a files content has changed?
I have some code but it doesn't refresh on a file change it refreshes every second. How can I do it when the file changes?
 Here is the code:

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>PHP Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">

</head>

<body>
    <?php
    $filename = "data.txt";
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    echo "<pre>$contents</pre>";
    fclose($handle);
    ?>

</body>
```

Comment: use ajax ... and execute script in interval

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
header( "Refresh:5; url=http://www.example.com/page2.php", true, 303);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fire an ajax request on every 5 seconds which will check either file is changed or not.

If file is changed the reload the page with javascript using

```
location.reload();
```